# Возврат значений от Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Всем привет. Отправляю запрос на сервер. Данные обрабатываются и через echo возвращаю строку.

Как можно сделать так, чтобы я возвращал не echo, а вернул две переменные, например, $s  и s2, и уже потом я с ними работал.

Я так понял, копать в строну json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, ответ ajax выдает как только php перестанет слать echo. То бишь отрабатывает единожды, и больше не будет общаться с сервером.  Соберите переменные в массив и закодируйте в `json_encode($array)`, а в js уже разбирайте.

Answer (score 0):

да. [копать и пилить](http://habrahabr.ru/post/42426/)